# ¿Como hacer que una funcion me devuelva un valor en visual basic?

Tags: vb.net

¿Alguien me puede decir por qué esto no devuelve valor? 
Le paso

```
Public Class Form1

Dim peso As Integer
Dim altura As Integer
Dim imc As Integer

Private Sub Calcular_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Calcular.Click
    peso = PesoBox.Text
    altura = AlturaBox.Text

    Resultado.Text = calcularimc(peso, altura, imc)

End Sub

Function calcularimc(ByVal peso As Integer, ByVal altura As Integer, ByVal imc As Integer) As Integer

    imc = peso / (altura) ^ 2

    Return imc
End Function


End Class
```

Comment: Puedes copiar el código completo, o una muestra en la web ideone? Cuando pasas el valor de `imc` para que lo calcule la función `calcularimc()` aun no tiene valor. Es más, no hace falta que lo pases como parámetro entiendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tu función devuelve un `Integer`. El cálculo que haces probablemente tiene como valor un decimal entre `0` y `1`, que al convertirse en `Integer` da como resultado `0`.Asi debe quedar tu función:

```
Function calcularimc(ByVal peso As Integer, ByVal altura As Integer) As Double
    Dim imc As Double = peso / (altura) ^ 2
    Return imc
End Function
```

Como ves he eliminado también de la función el parámetro `imc`, ya que no tiene sentido. Para llamarlo, simplemente:

```
Resultado.Text = calcularimc(peso, altura)
```

Comment: Gracias, soy nuevo en VB, era mi primerita vez, pensé que al menos me devolvería 3, 4 o algún valor jaja

Comment: De nada @AritzBello. Es importante tener siempre en cuenta los tipos de las variables, no es lo mismo `Integer` que `Decimal` que `Double`...Me alegra haberte ayudado :)